# Python function - if input variable doesn't exist then use default value

Tags: python, function, exception, default

```
def funcname(var1, var2 = "1234"):

    output = int(var2)

    return output
```

Is there a way to catch error in case where `var2` does not exist i.e. function defines a default value (above) and is called:

```
result = funcname(var1, var2 = cs)
```

but `cs` does not exist so in case where `cs` variable does not exist I would like `var2` to inherit the default value rather that error as `cs` not defined.

Comment: You can't catch the error *in* the function, because the error (referencing an undefined variable) occurs *before* the function is called.

Comment: Trying to use `cs` if it doesn't exist is a bug to be fixed anyway, not an error to catch at runtime.

Comment: The same function (which has evolved from a code snippet with appropriate conditions) is being used (at runtime) in two cases: one when `cs` exists and another when `cs` does not exist. Probably two functions are needed to replace the original code snippet.

Comment: you can only put `funcname(var1, var2 = cs)` in `try/except` and in `except` run this function without `cs`

Comment: I would rather set `cs = None` at the beginning of program (so it would exist always) and inside `function` I would check if `var2 is `None` and set `var2 = "1234"`.

Comment: Yes I'd done this `try:
    cs
    result=...   
except NameError:
    result=...   `. Was hoping there was something more elegant to contain everything in a library rather than partially in runtime code snippet.

Comment: `try: result = function(var1, cs) except NameError: result = function(var1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your situation you can use `try/except`

```
try: 
    result = function(var1, cs) 
except NameError: 
    result = function(var1)
```

But I would rather create variable `cs` at start with default value

```
cs = "1234"
```

and there is no problem with not existing variable.

Eventually I would use `None`

```
cs = None
```

and function would use `None` to recognize if it should use default value

```
#def funcname(var1, var2=None):
def funcname(var1, var2="1234"):
    if var2 is None:
        var2 = "1234"
    return int(var2)
```

---

In some tutorials/books I saw also `var2=object` when `None` is correct value which shouldn't be replaced or it should be replaced with different value then default value.

I neved had to use `object` for this so I'm not sure if I use it correctly in this example.

```
cs = None

def func(var1, var2=object):
    if var2 == object:
        var2 = "1234"
    elif var2 is None:
        var2 = "0"
    return int(var2)

print(func(1))       # 1234
print(func(1, 2))    # 2
print(func(1, None)) # 0
print(func(1, cs))   # 0
```

---

But I thing that the best would be create variable `cs` at start with some value.